# Проблема с получением ответа от стороннего сервера

Tags: angularjs, jsoup

отправляю запрос jsonP получаю ошибку

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
> ```

Кликаю в консоли копирую json в нотепад жму ctrl+shift+j виевер распознаёт как json

Код сервиса

```
Services.factory('Quests', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        var service = function () {
            this.test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            this.items = [];
            var url = 'http://quest/resource/testmail';
            this.resource = $resource(url,
                {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"},
                {
                    get: {method: "JSONP"}
                }
            );
        };


        service.prototype.load = function () {
            this.resource.get(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }


        return service;
    }]);
```

Брал от сюда пример http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-jsonp-apis.html

Немного по другому переписывал тоже самое

```
  {
         get: { method: 'JSONP', params: {property_code: 'DEMO_ERFOLGX', adults: '2',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
       }
```

Строка как то так выглядит

> testmail?adults=2&callback=angular.callbacks._0&property_code=DEMO_ERFOLGX:1

По хорошему насколько я понимаю должна выглядеть как то так

> &callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Заметил в чём причина, делаю запрос сюда `

> https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

` Срабатывает нормально, я как то не правильно отдаю данные на сервере, думал их просто нужно выкидывать в формате json, а оказывается не так просто, беру делаю так

> echo 'JSON_CALLBACK
>   ({"name":null,"salutation":"Halo","greeting":"Halo !"});';

Ругается на

> Uncaught ReferenceError: JSON_CALLBACK is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался
Так должно быть на сервере

> echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($temp).")";

так как ангуляр не отправляет  JSON_CALLBACK, а отправляет angular.callbacks._0 и бла бла